# Caulking small outdoor enclosures ( bat house/ birdhouse etc.)

Tags: plywood

I'm looking into build bat houses and water proofing the enclosure is a large part of most tutorials. Almost all suggest that you need to caulk all the seams.

None however are very specific on the type of caulk. To be clear I am not looking for brand recommendations as those would be clearly off topic. I am however looking for suggestions of the best *type* of caulk. Obviously I would not want to be using bathroom caulk outdoors. Last I checked there were oodles of choices.

I live in southern Canada so temperature would be a factor.

Comment: Aside from finishing issues that may come up, the DIY/Home Improvement stack exchange might be better suited to questions about caulk selection. http://diy.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @rob I already tried questions like this. They were closed as off-topic

Comment: That stinks. Well I hope you're able to find an answer somewhere. Otherwise I suppose any outdoor-rated or "doors & windows" caulk should work.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using something like a pine resin rather than caulk.  Keep it as natural as possible.  Also, please don't forget to reinforce the entrance to hinder squirrels from chewing through.  They will eat baby birds.